# Is it possible to get lower tier upgrade ingredients at a high level?

Tags: diablo-iii

As in the title, can I still get low tier ingredients at a high level, or will I only get higher tier ingredients? For instance, can "exquisite essence" still be gathered with a level 60+ character?

Answer (score 4):

No, [it was removed in patch 2.3](http://www.diablowiki.net/Exquisite_Essence).

Comment: although it's NOT what I wanted to hear, thanks for answering and doing so quickly

Comment: @JoshuaTodd if the answer has solved your problem, please mark is as "accepted" by clicking a checkmark on the right - this way other users will easily see that the problem was solved.